# Get image item name

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm getting a Image from sitecore with glass

```
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Icon Image")]
    public virtual Image IconImage { get; set; }
```

Now I need to get my image's item name. Is there any way of doing this without making another call to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the item name from the image source as the name in the path is always the item name:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(IconImage.Src)
```

Comment: Thats it! Exactly what I needed! Cheers